# I don't understand why my code works for an array of my struct but not with a struct containing an array of this struct?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct

So basically I'm trying to read a local json file about some spendings. I have a struct "Spending" and a struct "Spendings" that holds an array of Spending. I can't access the data from my json when I decode with the type Spendings.

I tried to decode with [Spending.self] which is working but I want to use my struct Spendings and I can't figure why it doesn't work?

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Métro 052",
        "price": 8.97,
        "date": "22/07/2019",
        "category": "Transport"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "National Geographic Museum",
        "price": 10.77,
        "date": "22/07/2019",
        "category": "Museum"
    }
]
```

```swift
enum Categories: String, Codable {
    case Transport
    case Food
    case Museum
    case Mobile
    case Housing
    case Gifts
    case Shopping
}

struct Spending: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var price: Float
    var date: String
    var category: Categories
}

struct Spendings: Codable {
    let list: [Spending]
}
```

```swift
//Not working
class SpendingController {
    static let shared = SpendingController()

    func fetchSpendings(completion: @escaping ([Spending]?) -> Void) {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "spending", ofType: "json") {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)), let spendings = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Spendings.self, from: data) {
                completion(spendings.list)
            }
        }
    }
}

//Working
class SpendingController {
    static let shared = SpendingController()

    func fetchSpendings(completion: @escaping ([Spending]?) -> Void) {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "spending", ofType: "json") {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)), let spendings = try? jsonDecoder.decode([Spending].self, from: data) {
                completion(spendings)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any error messages but in my completion when I print the result nothing is printed contrary to when I use [Spending].self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decoding a `[Spending].self` is indeed correct here because the root of your JSON is an array, which means that the type you use to decode should be `[XXX].self`.

Decoding a `Spendings.self` would be incorrect here because it would mean that you are a decoding an object root, as opposed to an array root. The `Spendings` struct has a single property `list`, so the JSON's root object would need to have a key of `"list"` in order for decoding `Spendings.self` to work correctly, like this:

```
{
    "list":
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Métro 052",
                "price": 8.97,
                "date": "22/07/2019",
                "category": "Transport"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "National Geographic Museum",
                "price": 10.77,
                "date": "22/07/2019",
                "category": "Museum"
            }
        ]
}
```